# woocommerce - list hidden products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a project where I need to list all hidden products in a page. I have created a shortcode for that and I have used following meta query, but it's not working.

```
$meta_query = array(
    'key'     => '_visibility',
    'value'   => array('hidden'),
    'compare' => 'IN'
);
```

Any idea why this is not working? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I have a similar problem, I've tryed with 
    $meta_query = array(
        'key'     => '_visibility',
        'value'   => 'hidden',
        'compare' => '='
    );
and it didn't worked either

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'product',
    'meta_key'      => '_visibility',
    'meta_value'    => 'hidden'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Then your usual loop worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce 3+ visibility has been [changed to a taxonomy instead of post meta](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/2.6.x-to-3.0.0-Developer-Migration-Notes#product-visibility-is-taxonomy-based-instead-of-meta-based) and if you're using `WC()->query->get_tax_query()` function call for building the args, you can just remove that call from setting `tax_query`.

IF you don't have access to the args or how they are built and it is ran through `get_tax_query` you can use the filter to remove the `NOT IN` tax query for visibility:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'smyles_show_all_products' );
// do something that calls some fn that makes product query
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'smyles_show_all_products' );

function smyles_show_all_products( $tax_query ) {

        foreach( (array) $tax_query as $t_index => $t_query ){

            if( isset( $t_query['taxonomy'], $t_query['operator'] ) && $t_query['taxonomy'] === 'product_visibility' && $t_query['operator'] === 'NOT IN' ){
                unset( $tax_query[ $t_index ] );
                break;
            }

        }

        return $tax_query;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Use this**

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
    'key' => '_visibility',
    'value' => array( 'catalog', 'visible' ),
    'compare' => 'IN'
    )
    )
```

Comment: This meta query will list all visible products. I need to list all hidden products.